# iOS Swift : Receiver type 'DataBase' for instance message is a forward declaration for the Objective C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton

I am getting the following compiler error for the Objective C code.

> Receiver type 'DataBase' for instance message is a forward declaration
>   for the Objective C code.

Swift code

```
@objc class SharedData : NSObject {

var dataBase : Database?

class var sharedData : SharedData {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance: SharedData? = nil
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        Static.instance = SharedData()
    }
    return Static.instance!
}
  }
```

Objective C code

```
SharedData *sharedData = [SharedData sharedData];
[sharedData.dataBase grabData];
```

My assumption is I messed up the swift singleton and I need a certain singleton that works with Objective C code, but I am not too sure. Also, this is just an example code, my real code is different and way more complex. However, this should demonstrate my issue.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer.